Does a Hexblood still need material components for their racial ability casting of Hex?
So Hex itself requires a Petrified Eye of Newt, recommended at 15gp. Now, this is in a campaign where the DM has ruled that every material component for a spell is consumed, regardless of the component. Given that, Hex has become a little pricey for a low-level party.
Now, Hexbloods have this racial feature:
- Hex Magic. You can cast the Disguise Self and Hex spells with this trait. Once you cast either of these spells with this trait, you can’t cast that spell with it again until you finish a long rest. You can also cast these spells using any spell slots you have.
When casting using this ability specifically, would the player have to still use the material components, or is it a freebie?

Heavily related on a different racial spell that has material components: Does a non-spellcasting Drow PC need material components to cast Dancing Lights?

If you're already in a setting that homebrews different rules for material components, why do you expect us to know what your DM will rule for this edge case?

Where do you get the idea that a petrified eye of newt has a recommended price of 15gp? Material components with no listed price are considered de minimus cost, to the point where a component pouch contains as many of them as needed, and a spellcasting focus removes the need to have them at all (if you have a class feature that allows use of a focus). Why is your DM ruling that all material components are consumed? The spells are balanced for most components not being consumed; this is a major nerf to many spells with costly components, more if they charge for the noncostly components too.

Also, what has the DM done to spellcasting foci and component pouches? If the answer is nothing, then get one of those and you're done. If the answer is something, please tell us, as it would affect the answers.

If you cast the spell, you need the components
Unless the feature says you don’t - like the Spell Scroll.

Unless you have a pouch/focus.

The rules for material components specify that

Casting some spells requires particular objects, specified in parentheses in the component entry. A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in “Equipment”) in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.

Despite the "recommend price" you cited in the original question, Hex does not indicate a cost for the petrified eye.

Components: V, S, M (the petrified eye of a newt)

So, you'll need the material component unless you have a pouch/focus.
